# Is the reward of reciting Qur'an in other languages same as reciting it in Arabic if one doesn't know how to read Arabic?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, fiqh, islamic-philosophy, quran-recitation

One of my sister in Islam don't know how to read Arabic so she wants to know that if she would read the Qur'an in any other language would she get the same reward as one gets when one recites the Qur'an in Arabic or would the reward be lesser than it?

Comment: Only the Arabic orally transmission is Qur'an.

Comment: @Medi1Saif please elaborate a bit.

Comment: It is really important to understand Qur'an while reading it. So it would be a nice thing to read it in a language we know as well as we would be able to follow it better in our lives. For the arabic part, she can start learning how to, it is never too late.